# Adding values to an empty DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, nullreferenceexception

I have an empty dataset added to my application. I want to populate it with some content. I do it in the following way

```
DataRow newrow = filteredLeads.Tables["filterLeads"].NewRow();
String fn = row.Field<String>("First Name");
String ln = row.Field<String>("Last Name");
Double ph = row.Field<Double>("Phone");
String ad = row.Field<String>("Address");

newrow["First Name"] = fn;
newrow["Last Name"] = ln;
newrow["Phone"] = ph;
newrow["Address"] = ad;

filteredLeads.Tables["Leads"].Rows.Add(newrow);
```

But i get an error on the last line saying system.nullReferenceException. My dataset is empty and i've defined a table on it name filterLeads. What's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DataSet` has table with name `filterLeads` not `Leads`. As you said in your question *defined a table on it name filterLeads*

*Change*

```
filteredLeads.Tables["Leads"].Rows.Add(newrow);
```

*To*

```
filteredLeads.Tables["filterLeads"].Rows.Add(newrow);
```

Comment: Thank you. Pardon my ignorance.